# Getting error no such container: cli when running hyperledger fabric samples first network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I was run successfully first network and fabcar, then i tried to run commercial paper. here i got this error no such container cli. now i tried back first network there is also the same error.

I am running hyperledger fabric 1.4 on ubuntu 18.4 with docker 18.x, everything was running fine but suddenly got the above error. tried different ways like changing docker-compose-cli.yaml to docker-compose.yaml, removed docker, docker compose and everything related like docker images and reinstall fresh docker and docker-compose, re clone fabric samples and docker images for samples...but still the problem exist.

here is error log:

`ERROR: .IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './docker-compose-cli.yaml'`
...

````
Error: No such container: cli
ERROR !!!! Test failed```

The ERROR shows that no such file or directory but i have the file docker-compose-cli.yaml in the same directory
````

Comment: show your run/up command?

Comment: `../first-network$ sudo ./byfn.sh up` @Adiii

Comment: Can you try With `docker-compose up -f docker-compose-cli.yaml`

Comment: I tried it but still not working. same error!

Comment: Why sudo? Running with sudo doesn't preserve your environmenth. If you can't run docker commands as your current user, do a sudo `usermod -aG docker <username>` to add the user to the docker group and then run without sudo. If you absolutely must run with sudo run `sudo -E` to preserve your environment.

Comment: For me, it looks like https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3875 what version of docker-compose are you using? `docker-compose version` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade your `docker-compose` version.

Comment: Yes i removed docker-compose 1.22 from snap that was not suitable, and download docker-compose 1.24.1 from github. now it working fine. For others, remove all docker-compose sometime it is in /snap/ directory and sometime in /usr/local/bin/ and download latest from github.com/docker/compose/releases/